# Post data with By posting data with 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and 'key': 'key'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I want to post data to the server using headers content-type: 'application/xww-form-urlencode'  but it fails because of the content type change to application/json

```
var headers= {
           'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
            'x-access-key': 'key'
}    
var data = {
      'twins' : twins
}    
axios.post('url', data, { headers: headers })
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          })
```

With Postman I successfully added the entry 
[image: By posting data with postman I set the headers like in image shown below]]
[image: and the body like this]

Answer (score 0):

In your headers change `content-type` to

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

If this doesn't work, then you I feel you might be using an interceptor. Which might be overriding your configuration.